# Why can Hamming-Codes only detect 2 errors?

Tags: hamming-distance

I understand that the simplified reason is that the maximum Hamming-Distance is 3. But I do not understand why this is the case. Why can't we have a bigger Hamming distance, even for very large codes?

Comment: You can make your Hamming Distance as big as you want. But then it's not a Hamming Code anymore ...

Comment: I see, but there must be a reason why the number is 3, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "reason"? It's a mathematical property which follows from the way the code is constructed.